# « Girl drink drunk » ?

Tags: anglais, prépositions, synonymes, genre-biologique, humour

« *Girl drink drunk* » ; la pathologie ou l'état d'une personne ([*drunk*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/drunk)) est qualifié par un [*drink*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/drink) dont le type est qualifié par le genre ([*girl*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/girl)). Ça provient d'un [gag](https://youtu.be/1GW22sAElpE), montrant comment sous le couvert d'un stéréotype on banalise parfois la consommation d'alcool, d'où les conséquences. On s'intéresse plutôt ici à la construction de l'emploi en adjectif pour l'état (temporaire) :

> [Saoul(e)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saoul) (préposition 1) [drink(s)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saoul) (préposition 2) fille/femme(s).

- Quelles prépositions choisit-on, pourquoi ; préfère-t-on une autre tournure (on peut aussi utiliser autre chose que *saoul* et *drink*) ?
- Y a-t-il un nom de boisson alcoolisée etc. qu'on pourrait substituer à la référence au genre et qui ferait le même... effet, en contexte ; une expression courante qui a trait à un type de drink ou d'alcool emblématiquement baroque, exotique, ou léger (en bouche) ?

Comment: Nothing to do with the context of your interesting question, but to confirm that I have the desired structure/usage straight (in English), would it be similar to using the (stereotypical?) noun phrase “man flu” (grippe d’homme) as an adjective (perhaps with a hyphen) to modify (downplay?) the state of being sick (i.e., “man[-]flu sick”)? Also off topic, but if so, do you think that “man flu” (and “girl drink” for that matter) would need a hyphen when used as an adjective?

Answer (score 10):

La notion de *girl drink* n'existe pas tellement en français. Pour rendre le contraste et le ridicule présent en anglais, je traduirais cette phrase en utilisant le nom d'une boisson pour enfants qui en plus n'est pas alcoolisée (pas alcoolique pour les puristes).

> Il s'est torché au Champomy.

Comment: La notion girl drink existe (pas celle de girl drink drunk), par contre elle très vulgaire et pas politiquement correcte, il suffit de rajouter "de gonzesse" après quoi que ce soit: "C'est une boisson de gonzesse". Mais j'aime beaucoup la traduction qui respecte l'esprit. +1

Comment: @P.Obertelli Quand j'ai dit que l'expression *girl drink* (boisson pour fille) n'existait **pas tellement** en français, j'aurais du préciser en français tel qu'il est parlé en France. D'autre part, je ne vois pas comment l'expression pourrait être considérée comme vulgaire ici mais misogyne, ça ne fait aucun doute.

Comment: Oui, plutôt que misogyne, j'aurais probablement du dire sexiste mais les notions sont proches ici. L'idée qu'un certain type de boisson (sucrées, douces, cocktails, aux couleurs vives, etc.) est spécifiquement destiné aux femmes rentre dans cette définition de misogynie trouvée sur Wikipedia : « Point de vue de celui qui se refuse à admettre l'égalité entre les hommes et les femmes » (Christian Godin).

Comment: Je vous invite conséquemment à voter pour la fermeture de la question. À mon avis un tel type de contenu n'a pas sa place sur le site. Merci.

Comment: C'est absurde. Nous sommes sur un site traitant de la langue française où (à peu près) toutes les expressions, politiquement correctes ou non, méritent d'être évoquées ou traduites. *Girl drink drunk* est très loin d'être ce que l'on peut rencontrer de pire dans le genre. J'ai néanmoins éliminé dans ma réponse le caractère sexiste de l'expression originale tout en tentant de préserver son côté comique.

Comment: Je comprends. Ce n'est pas que les réponses soient bonnes ou pas ou que ça soit intéressant ou pas mais au final il y a un impact net sur le préjugé et au lieu de le désamorcer avec la grammaire etc. il devient exacerbé avec les réponses où on finit par transposer sur les enfants, les homosexuels, les moins fortunés etc. même le mot féministe est sorti, et ma question ouvre la porte et je suis dans une position où je ne veux pas être associé à la promotion d'un stéréotype que je dénonce moi-même. Je ne peux supprimer la question. Le politiquement correct ne fait pas partie de mes mœurs. Merci.

Comment: from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that *If you posted a question that you regret posting because it is embarrassing, deleting the question is not a solution because users with 10K reputation can see it still anyway. It is also clear in the terms of service that you agree that all Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.
Moderators will not delete your question for the above reasons.*

Comment: La licence est irrévocable et ma contribution n'est pas qu'utilisable par SE uniquement mais par toute personne qui respecte les termes de la licence, ici ou ailleurs. Par ailleurs le droit à la non-attribution est limpide directement au [wiki de Creative Commons](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Requests_for_removal_of_attribution_contemplated). Ça n'a rien à voir avec la suppression du contenu. Sur meta on dit bien des bêtises en matière de propriété intellectuelle et il y a longtemps que je ne me fie plus à la compréhension qu'ont les utilisateurs de la licence. Merci.

Answer (score 4):

"drunk" -> "ivre", "saoul", "bourré"

Il y a toute une variété de subtilités sur les degrés de "drunkness" en français.

"drink" (dans le sens de "drink with alcohol") -> "boisson alcoolisée"

Ici le choix est assez pauvre. On pourrait aussi utiliser un nom de boisson plus spécifique, mais on ne couvrirait pas le sens anglophone de "drink"

"girl drink" -> boisson de femme, boisson de fillette, boisson de tapette/fiotte/autre synonyme insultant de "gay"

Ici on parle de boisson qui manque de virilité, d'une manière sexiste. En français on peut dire "boisson de femme" (par opposition à "boisson d'homme"), mais ça n'est pas très répandu. En revanche on dira plus souvent "boisson de pédé" ou autre, en choisissant l'insulte homophobe qui correspond au degré de familiarité de la situation. "Boisson de fillette" est un bon compromis, plus utilisé que "boisson de femme".

Enfin, la proposition sera "par de" si on est dans un registre soutenu, et "à" si on est dans un registre familier. "De" est à éviter car "ivre de XXX" est une expression qui signifie "qui est exalté par XXX", ce qui n'est pas ce qu'on cherche ici: ici on veut insister sur le fait que le type est minable car il ne tient pas l'alcool, pas décrire à quel point ce verre de cosmo lui a empli les sens.

En résumé, cela donne tout plein de possibilités de phrases. Voici une liste non-exhaustive où elles sont triées de la plus soutenue à la plus vulgaire:

> Passablement éméché par de la boisson peu virile
>
> Soûl/soûlé à la boisson de femme
>
> Bourré à la boisson de fillette
>
> Cuité à la boisson de pédale

Answer (score 3):

Il n'y a pas d'expression consacrée, mais la traduction littérale resterait compréhensible. Si on tient absolument à être sexiste je penses qu'on peut dire :

> Se torcher avec une boisson de/pour gonzesse

Mais n'importe quel alcool "doux" comme la bière ou le cidre devrait être compris, voir une boisson non alcoolique pour accentuer l'humour :

> Se torcher à l'eau gazeuse/au cidre

Answer (score 2):

It’s probably just my anglo tendency to associate being/getting drunk **“with”** whatever got/is getting me drunk, but I’d propose “avec” for the first missing preposition.

Granted, most of the hits for “se saouler avec” are in the context of “being in the company of …”, i.e., “avec les amis/copains,” but I’ve noticed that when the “avec” is followed by the thing that actually caused/is causing the state of drunkenness, it is often a product (or quantity thereof) that is not normally known for causing drunkenness, which could possibly be relevant here to the extent that “girl drinks” might be better known for their fruity sweetness than for their alcoholic strength and content.

see [“Comment se saouler **avec** une bière sans alcool?”](http://desencyclopedie.wikia.com/wiki/Comment_se_saouler_avec_une_bi%C3%A8re_sans_alcool_%3F) (from *Desencylopedie*) and [“Un homme ivre **avec** une seule bière!”](http://www.gentside.com/personnalit%E9/un-homme-ivre-avec-une-seule-biere_art393.html) (from *Gentside*)
cf : [“Un prolétaire se saoule **avec** du vin rouge. Un aristocrate se grise avec du champagne.”](http://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/citations/citation-42286.php) (from *Dicocitations*) for a normal (i.e., not a surprised “Tu t’es saoulé avec **quoi**?”) use of « avec » with a drink that is often associated with drunkenness.

For a replacement for “girl drink” that would not require a second preposition, “[la] liqueur” could work (but probably only) **in Quebe**c, where “liqueur” essentially means “soda pop” or “a sweet carbonated beverage” (non-alcoholic):

> “ivre/saoule/bourré(e) [qu’]avec [la] liqueur”

Perhaps «liqueur» and the above phrase could also work in places where «liqueur» does imply the presence of alcohol because some sweet liqueurs, although strong in alcohol content, were/are preferred by women, and might have been considered “girl drinks” at one time.
(You could consider adding “**de** femmes” to “liqueur” in the above suggestion, but I would do so with **great caution** because although what our Grandmothers meant by that phrase when they demanded a "real drink" might be relevant to your question, it’s current meaning [judging by the great majority of sketchy hits on Google] is not!)

One way to avoid the very nasty double entendre alluded to above were “ivre/saoule/bourré(e) avec [la/une] liqueur **de** femmes” to be used, would simply require changing the preposition to “pour,” as *L’Express* uses it in the headline: [“Pharrell Williams lance une **liqueur pour femmes**’](http://www.lexpress.fr/styles/saveurs/pharrell-williams-lance-qream-liqueur-destinee-aux-femmes_1015858.html):

“ivre/saoule/bourré(e) [qu’]avec [la/une] liqueur pour femmes”

Answer (score 0):

> *Bourré à l'eau de Cologne*

pourrait fonctionner, mais l'expression hexagonale la plus proche semble être :

> *Ivre, saoul, pompette, torché, pété, défoncé* à la **bibine**.

... les 'féministes' ajouteront les *-e* nécessaires.

Comment: @SurvenantLazurite Ni la bibine (en général bière de mauvaise qualité), ni la piquette (vin de mauvaise qualité, qui a tourné, qui pique) ne sont des boissons "de filles". Ce sont (c'étaient) plutôt des boissons "de pauvres" et plus consommées par des hommes.